# How do I detect which page I'm on within a paginated post?

Tags: posts, pagination, wp-link-pages

I'm using `wp_link_pages()` to paginate a post. I want to show something below the post content only on the first page of the post. Naturally I thought I'd use `get_query_var('paged')` to get the page number, but it returns 1 regardless of which page I'm on. I know I could parse out the URL manually to see which page I'm on, but there has to be a built in WordPress function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination query var on singular posts is `page`, not `paged`.

```
echo get_query_var( 'page' );
```